# Arrange json output by date

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I want to change the JSON output of a request, now it is arranged by when the record was created,

```
{"id":1,"title":"The Town","release_date":"2010-10-21","image":"/zX4fKmDXKGt4hlzhAJirdlRKFgO.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T19:57:58.449Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T19:57:58.449Z","movie_id":"23168","imdb_rating":"7.6"},
{"id":2,"title":"Interstellar","release_date":"2014-11-06","image":"/nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T19:58:16.600Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T19:58:16.600Z","movie_id":"157336","imdb_rating":"8.7"},
{"id":3,"title":"Django Unchained","release_date":"2013-01-16","image":"/5WJnxuw41sddupf8cwOxYftuvJG.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:22.411Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:22.411Z","movie_id":"68718","imdb_rating":"8.5"},
{"id":4,"title":"Moonrise Kingdom","release_date":"2012-05-30","image":"/uw88gWDC0W7AAEhMeQmtdXFV7yR.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:41.054Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:41.054Z","movie_id":"83666","imdb_rating":"7.8"},
{"id":5,"title":"Gone Girl","release_date":"2014-10-01","image":"/gdiLTof3rbPDAmPaCf4g6op46bj.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-05T09:05:08.424Z","updated_at":"2015-12-05T09:05:08.424Z","movie_id":"210577","imdb_rating":"8.2"}
```

But I want to arrange the data by release date, so it would look like this,

```
{"id":1,"title":"The Town","release_date":"2010-10-21","image":"/zX4fKmDXKGt4hlzhAJirdlRKFgO.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T19:57:58.449Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T19:57:58.449Z","movie_id":"23168","imdb_rating":"7.6"},
{"id":4,"title":"Moonrise Kingdom","release_date":"2012-05-30","image":"/uw88gWDC0W7AAEhMeQmtdXFV7yR.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:41.054Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:41.054Z","movie_id":"83666","imdb_rating":"7.8"},
{"id":3,"title":"Django Unchained","release_date":"2013-01-16","image":"/5WJnxuw41sddupf8cwOxYftuvJG.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:22.411Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T20:00:22.411Z","movie_id":"68718","imdb_rating":"8.5"},
{"id":5,"title":"Gone Girl","release_date":"2014-10-01","image":"/gdiLTof3rbPDAmPaCf4g6op46bj.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-05T09:05:08.424Z","updated_at":"2015-12-05T09:05:08.424Z","movie_id":"210577","imdb_rating":"8.2"}
{"id":2,"title":"Interstellar","release_date":"2014-11-06","image":"/nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg","user_id":null,"created_at":"2015-12-04T19:58:16.600Z","updated_at":"2015-12-04T19:58:16.600Z","movie_id":"157336","imdb_rating":"8.7"},
```

Would this be possible to do using Ruby on Rails?

*** EDIT ***

I use the above JSON data to place it into a $scope called `movies`. And then I use ng-repeat to output the data. I can't use `orderBy` in the repeat because I'm placing my items in rows. But I think it would also work if I would change the order in the `$scope.movies` so using javascript to rearrange the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you're working on json you could use

`json_array.sort_by { |json| Time.parse(json['release_date']) }`

2 notes here:

1. `Time.parse` for each item is an overhead (would be better) to do it before sorting (however for small sets it's not a problem)
2. `release_date` is not a Date but Time... which is a bit ackward. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure how I would implement your code. It looks like javascript, but I was hoping for a Ruby on Rails solution. If it is JS then how would I use it?

Comment: it's rails code

`json_array` is an array of items you listed. `sort_by` is a method available to all arrays in ruby (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html). In general it takes all items and sort array by a result of block you pass to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is going over my head a bit. First question, does the code go into the movies_controller.rb file and then the index definition?

Comment: ok. assuming you want to pass items sorted by release_date to your view, you may write it in your controller `@movies = json_array.sort_by { |json| Time.parse(json['release_date']) }`, instead of json_array put there a name of variable that keeps json items

Comment: Yea okay thought something like that. But I'm using AngularJS to handle the data. So I don't have a variable in RoR that keeps the json items. Maybe I should look for a javascript solution, and arrange the order of the objects inside my $scope.

Comment: I've never used Angular so I can't help. If data is passed to JavaScript via API then you may used code I wrote, otherwise you have to make JS version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97059/discussion-between-peter-boomsma-and-djaszczurowski).